# How to plot Horizontal Bar Chart in Bokeh (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bokeh, seaborn

I have this data:

```
data = {'Cities': {'Des_Moines': 80.0, 'Lubbock': -300.0, 'Minneapolis': 85.7,
                        'Orange_County': 80.0, 'Salt_Lake_City': 81.8, 'San_Diego': 80.0, 
                        'San_Francisco': -400.0, 'Troy': -400.0, 'Wilmington': -300.0}}
```

I have plotted this using `Seaborn` and it looks great.

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values('Cities', ascending=False)
sns.barplot(x='Cities', y=df_data.index, data=df_data, label='Cities', palette='Greens')
```

[image]

However, I'll like to embed this is a Flask web app using `Bokeh`.

I couldn't find an `horizontal barplot` in `Bokeh`. Even flipping the `x` and `y` axis do not seem to work. This is what I've done:
* Transposed `df_data` from `9x1` to `1x9`. Yet, I'm still not getting anything remotely nice.

```
bar = Bar(df_data.transpose(), df_data.columns.tolist(), stacked=False, responsive=True)

script, div = components(bar)
```

[image]

Notice that I still do not have `Horizontal` and my `category` axis is messed up.

Can anyone help modify this further?

Answer (score 7):

It's pretty easy to do with rect glyphs. Note that when you set the y_range with categorical values, the indexing of these in the bokeh plot starts at 1. That's why the counter "j" starts at 1.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import Range1d

data = {'Cities': {'Des_Moines': 80.0, 'Lubbock': -300.0, 'Minneapolis': 85.7,
                        'Orange_County': 80.0, 'Salt_Lake_City': 81.8, 'San_Diego': 80.0, 
                        'San_Francisco': -400.0, 'Troy': -400.0, 'Wilmington': -300.0}}
#df_data = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values('Cities', ascending=False)
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data).sort(columns='Cities',ascending=False)

this_series = df_data.loc[:,'Cities']

p = figure(width=800, height=600, y_range=this_series.index.tolist())

p.background_fill = "#EAEAF2"

p.grid.grid_line_alpha=1.0
p.grid.grid_line_color = "white"

p.xaxis.axis_label = 'xlabel'
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = '14pt'
p.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '14pt'
#p.x_range = Range1d(0,50)
#p.xaxis[0].ticker=FixedTicker(ticks=[i for i in xrange(0,5,1)])

p.yaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '14pt'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'ylabel'

p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = '14pt'


j = 1
for k,v in this_series.iteritems():
  print k,v,j
  p.rect(x=v/2, y=j, width=abs(v), height=0.4,color=(76,114,176),
    width_units="data", height_units="data")
  j += 1

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: For the rect glyph, the `x` and `y` kwargs specify the centroid of the rectangle; hence, the x coordinate of the center of the rectangle will be half of its width.

Answer (score 2):

You can go for the low level and reconstruct an horizontal bar plot using rect or [quad glyphs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/reference/models/glyphs.html#bokeh.models.glyphs.Quad). 
The above code is tentative and lack cities labels on y axis (no more time now...). But I hope this can help.

```
data = {'Cities': {'Des_Moines': 80.0, 'Lubbock': -300.0, 'Minneapolis': 85.7,
                    'Orange_County': 80.0, 'Salt_Lake_City': 81.8, 'San_Diego': 80.0, 
                    'San_Francisco': -400.0, 'Troy': -400.0, 'Wilmington': -300.0}}

from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import Range1d
from bokeh.palettes import Greens9
import numpy as np

cities = data['Cities']

p = figure(width=400, height=400)

bottom = -1
ii = -1
for k,v in cities.iteritems():
    bottom = bottom+1
    top    = bottom+1
    left   = 0
    right  = cities[k]
    ii += 1
    p.quad(top=top, bottom=bottom, left=left,
         right=right, color=Greens9[ii]) #"#B3DE69")

min_city = min(cities, key=cities.get)
max_city = max(cities, key=cities.get)
p.x_range = Range1d(start=cities[min_city], end=cities[max_city])

show(p)

# Can be done with rect glyph:
#p = figure(width=400, height=400)
#p.rect(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[1, 2, 3], width=0.2, height=40, color="#CAB2D6",
#       angle=np.pi/2, height_units="screen")
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there isn't one. This is the closest mention to it that I know of being [#1856](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/1856). For now only vertical bar [charts](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/reference/charts.html#module-bokeh.charts) are available:

> Bar Graph aka Horizontal Bar Graph (we currently don't have a chartfor)
>
> Column Graph aka Vertical Bar Graph (currently Bar)

Side Note: Transposing the data will work as you have tried, that is expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is none. 
One hack could be to use a custom css with rotate() 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp