# Bokeh Problem Rendering Plot in Flask App

Tags: python, flask, bokeh

My flask driven app works as expected with the high level Bar plot from Bokeh.

I now want to change the plot to a horizontal bar plot and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737079/how-to-plot-horizontal-bar-chart-in-bokeh-python) SO answer.

My code minus the formatting for brevity:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.util.string import encode_utf8
from bokeh.plotting import figure
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def test():
    kws = ["one", "two", "cat", "dog"]
    count = [23, 45, 11, 87]
    df = pd.DataFrame({"kw": kws,
                       "count": count
                       })

    df.sort("count", inplace=True)
    df.set_index("kw", inplace=True)
    series = df['count']

    p = figure(width=1000, height=1000, y_range=series.index.tolist())

    j = 1
    for k, v in series.iteritems():
        w = v / 2 * 2
        p.rect(x=v/2,
                y=j,
                width=w,
                height=0.4,
                color=(76, 114, 176),
                width_units="screen",
                height_units="screen"
                )
        j += 1

    #### get components ####
    script, div = components(p)

    page = render_template('test.html', div=div, script=script)
    return encode_utf8(page)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,
            threaded=False
            )
```

Located in `templates/test.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.9.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

{{ div | safe }}
{{ script | safe }}

</body>
</html>
```

This answer works in testing with `show(p)`. However the actual application takes the `p` object and gets the components `div` and `script` and embeds those in html.

When I run the app with `debug=True` I do not get an error just a hanging page.

EDIT: "Hang" is not accurate. I get a blank page.

Comment: You are loading a very old version of BokehJS from CDN in your template. Are you actually using Bokeh version `0.9` ? If not, the CDN versions should match the version that you have installed.

Comment: Good point...forgot about that. I'm using Bokeh 0.10.0 will change and try again.

Comment: @bigreddot that fixed it. Stoopid mistake...put that comment in an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Bigreddot's advice, I checked my version of Bokeh and adjusted the BokehJS version to match.

`conda list bokeh`  yielded:

```
bokeh                     0.10.0                   py27_0
```

I then changed my html and the minimal example works as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.10.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

{{ div | safe }}
{{ script | safe }}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone comes across this from now on please note that `bokeh.util.string import encode_utf8` has been removed since bokeh==2.0.0

In my case, with a flask app (using flask==1.1.2 and bokeh==2.0.2),  I was simply able to delete this line from the code and in the html render template, just `return html` rather than `return encode_utf8(html)`.