# Cant increase the size of whole chart in bokeh and make the chart in horizontal axis

Tags: python, bar-chart, data-visualization, bokeh

Hi I have data in the below Dataframe : 
[image: dataframe details]

I want to plot in a basic bar chart using Bokeh library but I can't increase the plot area so i am not getting a better looking graph due to variables > 50. 
[image: Bar Chart in Bokeh]
Any help/direction appreciated.

Also i want to plot in horizontal way.
Thank you !!

Comment: Chances are you can or have increased the width, but you cannot see it all on your current monitor/screen output environment. I have had this problem a few times. Try testing it on another scaled device. As for the horizontal bar, look up rect, it draws rectangles, and you can orient them as you wish, like here 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737079/how-to-plot-horizontal-bar-chart-in-bokeh-python/35371728

Answer (score 1):

For `bokeh.charts` usage, you can update [chart defaults](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.12.5/docs/user_guide/charts.html#chart-defaults):

```
from bokeh.charts import defaults

defaults.width = 450
defaults.height = 350
```

However, *please note:* `bokeh.charts` is effectively unmaintained at this point. I would actively discourage its use. The officially endorsed and recommended "High Level" API for use on top of Bokeh will be HoloViews (http://holoviews.org/) going forward. It is already much more capable than the the old `bokeh.charts` API and more importantly, very actively maintained. I would recommend to anyone to switch to it.

Comment: its not changing .. after replacing as recommended.Although for bokeh.plotting it does work .. , iam not able to do it for bokeh.charts

Comment: i am not getting any change with  plot_width and plot_height

Comment: I didn't notice you were using `bokeh.charts`, updated.